# Merging a branch A to master branch without deleting some modules in master that were deleted in branch A

Tags: git, gitlab

I initially created a master branch in my repository.
It contains 10 maven modules (module 1, ..., module10).

Then I decided to create a new branch, called branchA, from the master branch.
I removed 6 modules (module5, ..., module10) from branchA so it only contains 4 modules (module1, ...,module 4).

I made some modifications to the 4 modules inside branchA.
Now if i try to merge branchA to the master branch, the merge will merge the modifications i made on the 4 modules but i am afraid **the merge will also delete the 6 modules that were removed from branchA**.
I do not want that. All modules must remain in the master branch.

How do i avoid that ?

I am using git bash, eclipse and also the GitLab interface.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must find the commits which contain the module deletions.

If you can can isolate the deletions to a set of specific commits, then we can use an interactive rebase to drop those commits!

```sh
$ git rebase -i
```

Afterwards, we should replace any `pick` directives with `d` to drop that commit.

```sh
pick 72ef137 Some commit
d 28ecc32 module deletions
pick 0e751a0 Other commit
```

This will remove the commit(s) where the modules were deleted and allow us to merge in all the other commit(s) which remain.

[Bonus info on interactive rebases.](https://matthewsetter.com/git-interactive-rebase/)

Comment: Also, I guess I should not have created branch A the way I did. What is the correct way to create a branch from master branch, without running into the problem I encounter when I try to merge it back to master ?

Comment: This is the fastest way to resolve this. You need to know which commits the deletions happened in, else you will not be able to remove those commits.

Comment: The correct way to create a branch from master is as follows: `git checkout master` to make sure that you're on master, then `git checkout -b <BRANCH_NAME>`

Comment: And i will not encounter the same problem when i try to merge branch A to master ?

Answer (score 0):

You're right to worry that the merge might remove the files.  But this is not terrible!  You just need to put them back afterward.

The real question is *how to put them back* and there are multiple answers, with multiple different results.  *You must think about which result you want before you choose exactly what procedure to follow.*

#### Details

Remember these things about Git:

- Git is not about *files* and not even really about *branches*.  Git is all about *commits*.
- Each commit has its own unique hash ID.  A branch name just holds one commit's hash ID: **branch names are a way to *find* a commit.**
- Each commit holds the hash ID of its immediate predecessor commit(s), which Git calls the *parent commit* (or commits).  Again, that's some earlier commit's hash ID.  Hence **commits are a way to *find* (other) commits.**
- Each commit also holds a full snapshot of all of your files—or rather, all the files that are in that commit.  It sounds tautological when phrased as "the commit holds all the files that the commit holds", but the point here is that commits aren't *changes*, they're *snapshots*.

So, given that each commit points backwards to its predecessor, and each branch name points to the *last* commit in the series, what we have when we're ready to run `git merge` is something like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

The two branch *names* select the *last* commits.  These commits point back to their parents, which point back to another parent, and so on.  By starting at both ends and working backwards along both branches, Git finds the first—or really, the *last*—commit that's on *both* branches.  In this case that's easy; it's commit `H`.  In some more complicated cases:

```
...--A--B--C---F--G   <-- branch1
      \       /
       D--E--H--I--J--K--L   <-- branch2
```

it's not quite as obvious, but here again the commit with hash `H` is the best shared commit.  It looks like it's on `branch2`.  Well, it is on `branch2`, but it's *also* on `branch1`, thanks to merge commit `F`, which points back to *both* `H` and `E`.  Commits from `H` backwards, along the bottom row, are on *both branches.*  So are the commits from `A` on backwards.

Commits `B`, `C`, `F`, and `G` are only on `branch1`, though: we start at `G` and work backwards to `F`, and then to `C` and `B` and `A` and earlier, to find the commits that are on `branch1`.  It's just that at `F`, to find the commits that are on `branch1`, we *also* go back to `H`, then `E`, then `D`, and then `A` and so on.  We can get to `A` by two paths.  That's OK; the important thing is that we can get to A.

(This also means the commit I drew as `F` was made *after* the one I drew as `H`.  Usually I try to allocate the uppercase letters in order, but here I wanted to call the shared merge base `H` both times.)

#### How Git does a true merge operation

Let's go back to the more obvious diagram:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

We'll do `git checkout branch1; git merge branch2`, or we'll do `git checkout branch2; git merge branch1`.  The result will be the same either way, except for a few small details.

Since `H` has a snapshot, and each of the two branch-tip commits also has a snapshot, Git has to—and *can*—find *what changed* by doing two `git diff`s to compare two snapshots at a time:

- First, Git compares the merge base commit to one branch's tip commit.  If we start with the branch we have out, via `git checkout`, this represents *our* changes: the changes we made along our current branch, since the merge base.
- Then, Git compares the *same* merge base commit to the other branch's tip commit.  This represents *their* changes.

So we pick either commit `J` or commit `L`, by picking `branch1` or `branch2`, as the argument to our `git checkout`.  Then we pick the *other* commit by running `git merge` on the other name.  We *could* do this by raw hash IDs, too, up to a point, but generally we don't because the names are a lot easier to type in, and actually mean something to humans.  For now, let's pick `branch1` as the one we check out, then merge `branch2`:

```
git checkout branch1; git merge branch2
```

Git will now run, internally, the equivalent of:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

These will find the two sets of changes that Git should combine.

Since we *deleted* a bunch of files along one of these two paths, the diff will say *delete file module5* for instance.

If *they* **changed** file module5, we'll get a *delete/modify conflict*.  That is, Git will tell us: *I don't know how to both **delete** module5 and **keep** it but **change these lines**.  You figure it out for me.*

If they didn't touch module5, Git will say *I know how to handle this!  Delete the file!*  So the combination of the two will include deleting the file.

Git will go on to combine all of our changes with all of their changes.  Whenever Git can't do this on its own, it will declare a conflict.  When it has processed all files from both sets of changes, it has:

- no conflicts at all: the combine changes are good; Git gets the contents from `H`, applies the *combined* changes, and is done; or
- some conflicts: Git combines all that it can, leaves us a mess in Git's index and our work-tree, and stops with a conflict.

If Git stopped here with a conflict, it is now our job to resolve the conflicts and produce the correct result.  Otherwise, **by default** Git will go on to make a new *merge commit*.  We can choose to tell it, when we start, *do not go on to make a merge commit even if you think you can.*  To do that, we add `-n` or `--no-commit` to our initial `git merge` command.

Suppose that we did that, or that Git stopped in the middle of the merge to force us to resolve the conflicts.  Either way, we now have what looks like a normal bash prompt in a normal Git-repository-state.  That is, we have that unless you've set up some extra information, because we're not in a normal Git state.  We're in a "still merging" state.  If you've set your bash prompt up this way, it now shows this "still merging" state.  In any case, `git status` tells us that we're still merging.

#### The index is now all-important

It is now our job to put into the *index* (Git's index) the *correct result of the merge*.  We control everything here!  And, if you don't know what the index is, now is the time to learn.

The *index*, which Git also calls the *staging area*, has multiple purposes.  I like to say that the main one is that the index is *where you build the next commit you will make.*  The index contains a copy of each file.<sup>1</sup>  The copy that you can see and edit in the work-tree is not the copy that Git uses when Git makes a new commit.  The *index* copy is the one Git uses for the next commit.  So the files that are in the index represent the next commit you will make.  The work-tree copy is there so you can see (and edit!) it, but it's not the one Git will use.

During a conflicted merge, however, the index expands.  Instead of holding *one* copy of each file, it holds up to *three* copies.  The three copies of the file are:

1. The copy from the merge base, in staging slot #1.
2. The copy from the `HEAD` commit (`branch1` or commit `J` here), in staging slot #2.
3. The copy from the other commit (`branch2` or commit `L` here), in staging slot #3.

There's still a copy of the file in your work-tree, where you can see and edit it, too, but that's not the one Git will use.  Right now, there *isn't* one for Git to use, because `git commit` needs a copy in staging slot zero.

It's your job, now, to come up with the right file(s) and put them into staging slot zero of the index.  Files that Git thinks it already merged are already there, in slot #0; files that Git thinks are *unmerged* are occupying these other #1, #2, and/or #3 slots.  You can use `git checkout-index` or varieties of `git show` or `git checkout` to access these extra slot copies, or you can just work with what you have in your work-tree, where you can see and work with files.

Usually the work-tree is a lot easier.  Commands like `git mergetool` do work directly with the index (using `git checkout-index` and `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index` and the like, all the raw low level tools) but that's all optional.  You can also use `git show <commit>:path` or `git checkout commit -- path` to extract particular files from particular commits.

There is a lot to know about here: the index is a complicated little beastie.  In particular, if you use:

```
git checkout <commit> -- <path>
```

this will:

- take a file from a commit;
- copy it into index slot #0, erasing slots 1, 2, and 3 in the process; and then
- copy the file to your work-tree

so this process automatically resolves a merge conflict.  On the other hand:

```
git checkout --ours <path>
```

or:

```
git checkout --theirs <path>
```

copies a file from index slot #2 or #3 respectively, to your work-tree.  This *does not* put anything in slot zero, so the file remains conflicted; it's just that you can now *see* the file, because there is a copy in your work-tree.

In both cases, the old copy in your work-tree is *gone*, so before you use any of these, be sure you don't mind that.

Your job, once again, is to *resolve each conflict*.  You do this by putting a *correct* copy of the file into slot zero.  The *usual* way to do this is to use `git add`, or sometimes `git rm`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, the index contains the file's *name and mode* and a *reference* to a Git blob object.  It's this Git blob object that will hold the file's content in the next commit.  But it's easier to mostly think about this as "a copy of the file", and except for using the low level `git update-index` and `git ls-files --stage` commands, thinking of the index as holding copies of all the files works fine.

---

#### Using `git add` and/or `git rm`

When you run:

```
git add path/to/file
```

your Git reads the given file from your work-tree, compresses it down into the internal Git format ready for committing, and writes a copy of that file into the index, at staging slot zero.

In normal (non-conflicted-merge) situations, this simply updates the copy of the file that will go into the next commit.  In merge-conflict situations, this *erases* the other three slots and puts the file in slot zero, where it is ready for committing.

If the file *should not be* in the next commit at all, you can use `git rm` to *remove* all copies from the index.  You'll occasionally get a complaint here, but the file *will* be removed.  Or, you can use plain `rm` to remove the file from the work-tree, then use `git add`.  Peculiarly, if the file in the work-tree is *gone*, `git add` simply removes it from the index.  You can think of it as *make the index match the work-tree* instead of *copy from work-tree to index*, to make sense of this, though I still like to think of it as "copy from work-tree to index" myself.

Once you have added, or removed, all conflicted files, `git status` will show you a status with no unmerged files.  This is true even if you started with no conflicted files: if you ran `git merge --no-commit branch2` and there were no conflicts, the merge stopped, and you were in the middle of the merge, but there were no conflicted files.

Still, at this point you can `git add` or `git rm` any *additional* files you care to add or remove.  So if Git successfully merged commits `J` and `L` by removing some module files, but you want all the files to exist after all, now is a good time to get them back:

```
git checkout <any-commit-that-has-the-files> -- module5 module6 ... moduleN
```

In your case, commit `L`, as identified by `branch2`, has the files, so:

```
git checkout branch2 -- module5 ...
```

does the trick.

Again, this kind of `git checkout` copies the files from the given commit, to the index, and then to your work-tree.<sup>2</sup>  You can now see them, *and* the files are there, ready to be committed, in the index.  `git status` will continue to show you useful information.

---

<sup>2</sup>This kind of `git checkout` is now a separate command, `git restore` with various options, in Git version 2.23 and later, but you can still use `git checkout`.  The reason for separating this kind of `git checkout` from the other kind—also still available as `git checkout`, but spelled `git switch` in 2.23 and later—is that `git checkout [<commit>] -- path` will *destroy uncommitted work without warning*.  The kind of checkout that `git switch` does *warns* about uncommitted work, and the kind of checkout that `git restore` does *clobbers without warning*.  Putting these both in one command is obviously dangerous.  Separating them into two commands, one "safe" and one "dangerous", is better: it gives you a big clue, before you hit enter, to double check that you *really meant to do that*.

---

#### When you are ready, finish the merge

Now that you've got everything arranged to have the *correct result* you can finish the merge:

```
git merge --continue
```

or:

```
git commit
```

(these do the same thing except that the `merge --continue` is a little safer in that it checks, *are we finishing a merge?*, before running `git commit`, so it's a sort of sanity check).

The result is a new commit.  Like any commit, it has the previously-checked-out commit as its (first) parent.  Unlike normal commits, though, it has a *second* parent, too.  The *second* parent is the commit you named when you ran `git merge branch2`.

So now, we have:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

That is, the *name* `branch1` now select commit `M`, the new merge commit you just made.  Commit `M`'s *first* parent is the commit that was the tip of `branch1` a moment ago: commit `J`.  Commit `M`'s *second* parent is commit `L`.

The *snapshot* for merge commit `M` is whatever you had in the index when you ran `git commit`.

If you *put back* files that `git merge` deleted, when it combined your changes with their changes, well, now your snapshot *doesn't* delete those files.  Comparing the snapshot in `M` against the one in `J` will show some files *added*.  Comparing it against the snapshot in `L` shows nothing at all for these files: the files in `L` match those in `M`, and Git only *tells you* about files that *don't* match.

#### You can fix the problem after merging instead

Suppose you simply let `git merge` delete the files, to carry the deletion forward.  This makes your `git merge` a lot easier.  You don't need `--no-commit` and if Git successfully deletes the files on its own, Git can make the merge commit on its own.  You end up with:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

which is the same *graph* as before; it's just that merge snapshot `M` *doesn't have the module files*.  If you diff `J`-vs-`M` you see changes brought in because of `H`-vs-`L`; if you diff `L`-vs-`M` you see changes brought in because of `H`-vs-`J`, including the module-file deleting.

In other words, `M` is the *natural result* of the merge, rather than a *carefully hand-crafted, corrected result*.

You do want those files, though.  So suppose you now run:

```
git checkout branch2 -- module5 ...
git commit
```

Make your commit message read something like "put back module files needed but mistakenly deleted earlier".  (Coming up with a really good log message is often tricky.)  Now you have:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

where commit `M` is non-functional, but commit `N` fixes it.

There's nothing inherently wrong with this, and it's a natural way to work.  It does leave you with a "bad" commit, but in some sense, that's because commit `J` itself is "bad".

#### You can fix the problem *before* merging instead

Your problem here is that `J` lacks these module files, that exist in `H` and `L`.  But you can make a new commit *before* you merge.  Just `git checkout branch1` and put the files back:

```
git checkout branch1
git checkout <hash-of-H-or-L or use the name branch2 here> -- module5 ...
git commit -m "put back module files mistakenly deleted..."
```

or:

```
git checkout branch1
git revert <hash of commit that deletes module files by mistake>
```

if the commit that deletes the module files is standalone (if not, this might revert too much).  Now you have:

```
...--G--H--I--J--N   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \
          K-----L   <-- branch2
```

Now you can run `git merge branch2` to get:

```
...--G--H--I--J--N--M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \         /
          K-------L   <-- branch2
```

Because `N` *has* the module files, the diff from `H` to `N` *does not* says to delete them.  There is no deletion operation to combine with the work found by diffing `H` vs `L`.  The merge therefore *does not* delete the module files.

#### Which is the right way?

All of these are "right" in that they all produce a correct final commit.  None of these are "right" in that none of them is better than another.  You pick what you want, from the menu of options.  Git is a set of tools for making commits.  Make the commits you want, using the tools.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation. I dare to say however that i am not too sure it will help me fix my problem as I really do not want to put these deleted modules back in branch A to make sure they will not be deleted when i merge it to the master branch. The idea of branch A is that it is a branch for a developer who needs to work on modules 1 to 4 only. It is a subset of the 10 modules contained in the master branch.

Comment: Again, *branches don't matter*. Only *commits* matter. Make a new branch name to refer to commit `J`. Then: merge and fix to make `M`, or merge, then fix to make `N`, or make `N`, then merge. The end result is that your new branch *name* now refers to the last commit you've made at this point. Or, make the commits, then set the new branch name, then rewind the old branch name to point to commit `J` again. The branch names don't matter, because you can move and change them. Only the *commits* matter.